# Create Custom Rxjs Observable for network

Tags: javascript, networking, rxjs

I'm a beginner with Rxjs, I'm working on a game project have a network implement is:

Send by function `sendPacket`, and server response comes in fuction `onReceived`

```
sendPacket: function(packet) {
  this._tcpClient.sendToServer(packet);
}
onReceived: function (pkg) {
}
```

I want to refactor the current network struct like Angular HttpClient:
sendPacket return an `Observable` and I just need `subscribe` like this:

```
network.sendPacket(myPacket).subscribe(response => ...)
```

How can I implement this idea? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the problem is that your onReceived is a "global" function that isn't directly associated with the sending of the packet.  In which you need to store the observer for use later where it  can be accessed within onReceived.  Something like:

```
let savedObserver = null;

sendPacket: function(packet) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this._tcpClient.sendToServer(packet);
    savedObserver = observer;
  })
}

onReceived: function (pkg) {
  if (savedObserver) {
    savedObserver.next(pkg);
    savedObserver.complete();
    savedObserver = null;
  }
}
```

However, the above assumes there can only ever be 1 request at a time.  To allow for multiple parallel requests you need to store an observable per request, then be able to link the response to the request and find the correct observable.

Answer (score 1):

there are answers in this article, it's for absolute beginners so you should catch everything.

if you are interesting only in Observable that makes request, scroll down to the end

https://justeugen.medium.com/rxjs-for-beginners-1-c87f92f4a9d2

Comment: Thank you, I have read your article, but my API don't have function fetch like your. I must call sendPacket then wait to when onReceived is called

Comment: Can you display how it looks in your code?

Comment: `sendPacket(function () { this._tcpClient.send(pk); };` 


The API `this._tcpClient.send` doesn't return anything. I must wait until the `onResponsed` function is called that meaning server has responded